# Solve for $x$ in $y= \frac{x-1}{2x+3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been raking my brain for the solution to this problem for a while, and have searched as best I could for an answer.

I have to solve for $x$ in the equation: $$y= \frac{x-1}{2x+3}$$
Since $(x - 1)$ is not a factor of $(2x+3)$ and I can't figure out how to separate out $x$ once I reach the stage of $y(2x+3) = x-1$ I've gotten stuck.

Answer (score 7):

$y(2x+3)=x-1$

$2xy+3y=x-1$

$3y+1=x-2xy$

$3y+1=x(1-2y)$

$x=\frac{3y+1}{1-2y}$

Simply expand, group the terms with $x$ on one side, and factorise.

Comment: Thank you so much, It's been so long since I've done this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$y=\frac{x-1}{2x+3}$$$$y=\frac{(2x+3)-5}{2(2x+3)}$$$$y=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{5}{2(2x+3)}$$
$$\frac{5}{2(2x+3)}=\frac{1}{2}-y=\frac{1-2y}{2}$$
$$2x+3=\frac{5}{1-2y}$$
$$2x=\frac{2+6y}{1-2y}$$
$$x=\color{red}{\frac{1+3y}{1-2y}}$$

Comment: Though mathematically correct, wouldn't this be a little difficult for the OP to understand ?

Comment: In my opinion, yes, some of the steps weren't so clear.